# unexpectedly found nil in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have code like this in my controller:

```
var itemList:[String] = []

@IBOutlet var tasksTable:UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return itemList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel.text = itemList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tasksTable.reloadData() <-----------------------
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

**ERROR:** unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because at the moment `viewWillAppear` is called, `tasksTable` is nil. You probably forgot to hook up the outlet in the nib.

Comment: I have hooked up outlet. But, initially the array will be nil. is there any way to deal with nil array?

Comment: This is actually a really nice feature of Swift. If this had happened in Objective-C, _nothing_ would have happened; your table view wouldn't work but you wouldn't know why. This way, Swift slaps you for not hooking up the outlet.

Comment: No, the array (`itemList`) will never be nil. Not the way you've written your code. It can be empty but it can never be nil. Again, that's a really great Swift feature.