# get two tableviews in one view controller using segment in swift 4.0 without using XIB CELL

Tags: ios, swift4

I have two tableviews and and one segment control on first segment click i should get the first table and second segment click I should get the second tableview while running the app I got the exception error like this

> (Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

[image]

My ViewController Code:

```
import UIKit

class DemoTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
struct structOne {
    let cell : Int
    let one : String
}

struct structTwo {
    let cell : Int
    let two : String
}

var arrayOne = [structOne]()
var arrayTwo = [structTwo]()
@IBOutlet weak var tableOne: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var segmentDemo: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var tableTwo: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    arrayOne = [structOne(cell: 0, one: "One"), structOne(cell: 1, one: "One"), structOne(cell: 2, one: "One")]

    arrayTwo = [structTwo(cell: 0, two: "Two"), structTwo(cell: 1, two: "Two"), structTwo(cell: 2, two: "Two")]

    self.tableOne.delegate = self
    self.tableOne.dataSource = self

    self.tableTwo.delegate = self
    self.tableTwo.dataSource = self

    self.tableTwo.isHidden = true
    self.tableOne.isHidden = false

    self.tableTwo.reloadData()
    self.tableOne.reloadData()

    self.tableTwo.tableFooterView = UIView()
    self.tableOne.tableFooterView = UIView()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func segmentAction(_ sender: Any) {
    switch self.segmentDemo.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        self.tableTwo.isHidden = true
        self.tableOne.isHidden = false
        self.tableOne.reloadData()
    case 1:
        self.tableTwo.isHidden = false
        self.tableOne.isHidden = true
        self.tableTwo.reloadData()
    default:
        break
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableOne.isHidden == false{
        return arrayOne.count
    }
    else {
        return arrayTwo.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableOne.isHidden == false{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "One") as! OneTableViewCell
        cell.lblOne.text = arrayOne[indexPath.row].one
        return cell
    }
    else {
       let tcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Two") as! TwoTableViewCell
        tcell.labeltwo.text = arrayTwo[indexPath.row].two
        return tcell
    }
}
```

Here is my First Cell code:

```
import UIKit

class OneTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblOne: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Here is my second cell code:

```
import UIKit

class TwoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labeltwo: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Error clearly says that something is nil, check the line, debug what is nil, handle the error then.

Comment: Your table view cell is nil check all thing properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unexpectedly found nil in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681695/unexpectedly-found-nil-in-swift)

Comment: @SharadChauhan I can't understand what is going nil can you please help me

Comment: Try to print these values arrayOne[indexPath.row].one and arrayTwo[indexPath.row].two

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya there's no segment in that code and no struct and I have all that in my code!!! as per me!!!

Comment: Have you created the nibs for `TableViewCell` ?

Comment: @AudreyRozario Whatever your controls is but you are getting nil is then main answer !! that is common mistake done by beginners

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava no

Comment: @AudreyRozario then ?

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava i have created the cells in their respective tableview cells i have not created any xib

Comment: Instead of creating 2 `UITableView` add only 1 `UITableView` and load different data based on `segment` selection.

Comment: @Kuldeep how can i do that

Comment: @AudreyRozario, you can also upvote my answer.

Comment: @Kuldeep done!!

Comment: @AudreyRozario, the answer that I posted yesterday and you accepted.

Comment: I have already upvoted for it @Kuldeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example You have  these 2 array.

```
var arrFirst    = ["One", "One", "One", "One", "One"]
var arrSecond   = ["Second", "Second", "Second", "Second", "Second"]
```

Define this globally

```
var nSelectedSegmentIndex : Int = 1 // 1 is for 1st SelgmentItem
```

**UITableView Code**

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if nSelectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            return arrFirst.count
        }
        else {
            return arrSecond.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TableViewCell = self.tblVW.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if nSelectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = arrFirst[indexPath.row]
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = arrSecond[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

**Segment Action**

```
@IBAction func segmetnValueChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        self.nSelectedSegmentIndex = 1
    }
    else {
        self.nSelectedSegmentIndex = 2
    }
    self.tblVW.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @AudreyRozario, what's your question?

Comment: Can you help me with my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540100/i-am-trying-to-get-particular-logged-in-user-data-in-the-profile-in-swift-4

Answer (score 1):

Try this and please read about [Swift Optionals] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_optionals.htm)

```
cell.lblOne.text = arrayOne[indexPath.row].one!
```

Please register your `OneTableViewCell` and `TwoTableViewCell` in `viewDidLoad` method,

If you are using `XIB` for `UITableViewCell`, you should use this,

```
tblList.register(UINib(nibName: "OneTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OneTableViewCell")
```

Do it same for `TwoTableViewCell` and let me know in case of any queries.

**UPDATE**

```
struct structOne {
    let cell : Int
    let one : String
}

struct structTwo {
    let cell : Int
    let two : String
}

enum SelectedIndex: Int {
    case TableOne = 1
    case TableTwo = 2
}
```

Initial declaration,

```
var currentSeletedIndex : SelectedIndex = .TableOne
var arrayOne = [structOne]()
var arrayTwo = [structTwo]()
```

Implement `UITableViewDataSource`,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if currentSeletedIndex == .TableOne {
        return arrayOne.count
    } else {
        return arrayTwo.count
    }
}
```

Now `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OneTableViewCell") as! OneTableViewCell
    if currentSeletedIndex == .TableOne {
        cell.lblOne.text = arrayOne[indexPath.row].one
    } else {
        cell.lblOne.text = arrayTwo[indexPath.row].two
    }

    return cell
}
```

Your SegmentControl action,

```
@IBAction func segmentValueChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    currentSeletedIndex = SelectedIndex(rawValue: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)!
    tblList.reloadData()
}
```

This code is tested and working properly.

Comment: tblList.register(UINib(nibName: "OneTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OneTableViewCell") do i Have to write this code in viewDidLoad ????

Comment: @AudreyRozario if you are using xib then you have to write it

Comment: i have created the cells in their respective tableview cells i have not created any xib

Comment: then no need to do it

Comment: Please don't reload any table on segment selection

Comment: Use only one table instead of two tables

Comment: how can i populate two arrays in one tableview

Comment: on segment selection you have to decide what to display in it

Comment: This did work for me too!!! I tried upvoting for you but its not allowing me to do that its only allowing me to upvote for one... :(

Comment: @AudreyRozario Yes Please

Comment: can you help me with my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540100/i-am-trying-to-get-particular-logged-in-user-data-in-the-profile-in-swift-4